# Invalid config server configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am on learning stage of Spring Cloud & using spring version 2.4.3 and spring-cloud-version

2020.0.1 and I created two property file

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-server
 
server:
  port:  8888
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/************/insurance-config-server
        default-label: main
```

but still I got following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

How to solve this kind of error?

Comment: Hopefully I didn't mess up any of the format you intended it to be. Your attempt was quite unreadable...

Comment: You don't need bootstrap.properties anymore. Please go through the tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: for 2020.0 bootstrap is no longer needed, move the configuration to application.yml

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a bootstrap.yml file?

I had the same problem. My project did not have a bootstrap.yml, but I specified a dev activity file in the IDEA startup configuration, which caused the same error as you did. The error could not be found bootstrap.yml on startup. After deleting dev in IDEA startup configuration, it can start normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the example in the book you referenced then I will suggest you move this

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/************/insurance-config-server
        default-label: main
```

to `application.yml`

That is what I did and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but my mistake was adding the config properties in the bootstrap.yml file instead of application.yml. So, you can check if that is your mistake.